# Integration of CoSign web Agent with Web Portal

Tags: cosign-api

1. Following url and parameters names for testing integration is correct or not ??

URL:-  http://webdemos.arx.com/cswa_sign_sample/CSWADemo.asx

Parameter name:- inputXML .

2. Do you have any sample code in java for this integration?

Comment: Re: Sample Java code -- what part are you having difficulty with? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks Larry K...I am trying to integrate our web portal with your cosign. I am following the following steps please correct if i am wrong:-1.   I am sending a  post request on  "https://webagentdev.arx.com/Sign/UploadFileToSign" with parameter inputXML. In input XML i am sending a document stream encrypted with base 64.  2. After receiving the session id in response i will send a get request with sessionid as a parameter.

Comment: After you receive the sessionID in response, you send a redirect to the human sitting at the browser. If you want more info, please ask as a new question on stack overflow.

Answer (score 0):

The service point for the Developer CoSign Web Agent platform is **https://webagentdev.arx.com/**

Eg. https://webagentdev.arx.com/Sign/UploadFileToSign

[Documentation on the UploadFileToSign method](http://docs.arx.com/CoSign_APIs/doc_v7.1/Default.htm#doc_7.1/Request%20Format.htm)

Comment: Thanks Larry K ..... I am getting connection timeout error when i am sending a post request on "https://webagentdev.arx.com/Sign/UploadFileToSign".

Comment: You can use the [API test tool](http://webagentdev.arx.com:88/testApp/) to check your XML

Comment: I would also try with a small PDF to start with.